# Optimizing ActiveRecord query Attribute with where

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I have a model with the these two methods `project_lead` and `project_operative_lead`.

When ever i try to fetch these two attributes i get a ton of queries. Even though I'm trying to use includes.

Here is my model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_sales_contributions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sales_contributors, through: :project_sales_contributions, source: 'employee'

  has_many :project_contributions,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contributors, through: :project_contributions, source: 'employee'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_customer_contacts,
    :project_contributions,
    :project_sales_contributions,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: :all_blank

  def project_lead
    project_contributions.where(role: 'lead').map { |e| e.employee.name }
  end

  def project_operative_lead
    project_contributions.where(role: 'operative_lead').map { |e| e.employee.name }
  end

end
```

This is my include statement:
`Project.includes(:customer, project_contributions: [ :employee ]).all`

However i still get n+1 queries.

Is there any way i can reduce the number of queries?

Comment: Hey you can used your method as `project_contributions.includes(:employee).where(role: 'lead').map { |e| e.employee.name }` actually in your map is N+1 query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `where` clause acts on an `ActiveRecord` object. `project_contributions` is an `Enumerable` so you can do iterative methods on it like `map` , `select` etc. The table doesn't have to be queried again to get what you want.

Btw why not use `joins` here instead? You could use `joins` instead of `include`. With `includes` you are eagerly-loading the `customer` model which is an overkill in your case since you aren't using the attributes of that `Customer` model, I think. Just my two cents.

```
Project.joins(:customer, project_contributions: [ :employee ]).all
```

Answer (score 0):

You queried for project_contributions again so it breaks the includes, you could try to select instead:

```
project_contributions.select{ |e| e.role == 'lead' }.map{ |e| e.employee.name }
```